# Ruby class variables in metaclass

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have a ruby class like this:

```
class C
  @@v = 1

  class << self
    p @@v  # everything goes well here
  end
end

class << C
  # here I get an exception 
  # `singletonclass': uninitialized class variable @@v in Object (NameError)
  # from a.rb:5:in `<main>'

  p @@v
end
```

My question is: the exception said 'uninitialized class variable @@v in Object (NameError)', but why ruby lookups class variables in Object(main)?

It seems like ruby always lookups metaclass' class variables outside it.

Comment: When you did 'class << c you really are using self, which is main , which is under Object, right?

Comment: @vgoff What did mean: **When you did 'class << c you really are using self**

Comment: In your second class << self definition, the scope is main, again.  Yet there is no class variable @@v defined in that scope.  So wouldn't you expect to get that error?

Comment: @vgoff Why the scope is still main? As far as I know when a class defined ruby will change it's scope.

Comment: I believe that this is a problem of Ruby. Top and bottom code should give identical results. Please report the problem in http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/

Comment: The fact that the last class << C is outside of any other scope, means it is at main.  The first is within the scope of class C, as it is being defined inside class C itself.

Answer (score 3):

You have defined the class variable `@@v` for the class `C`.  We shouldn't be surprised that this:

```
class << C
  p @@v
end
```

raises an exception, because here we are dealing with the [singleton class](http://www.devalot.com/articles/2008/09/ruby-singleton) of `C`, for which we have not defined a class variable `@@v`.

The *real* question is, **why does it work when you do it this way?**

```
class C
  @@v = 1

  class << self
    p @@v
  end
end
```

The answer appears to be that, for your convenience, whenever you access the singleton of a class *from inside that class,* Ruby transparently gives you access to that class's class variables.

Note that this works consistently when you define methods as well, whether you use the `class << self; def method_name` syntax or the `def self.method_name` syntax:

```
# assuming @@v in C is 1
class C
  def self.print_v_from_inside
    p @@v
  end
end

def C.print_v_from_outside
  p @@v
end

C.print_v_from_inside
# => 1

C.print_v_from_outside
# => NameError: uninitialized class variable @@v in Object
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is a problem of Ruby. Top and bottom code have same self and class and should give identical results. Please report the problem in http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/